# Modifying the interpreter in Scheme

Tags: scheme, racket, interpreter

I'm totally new in Scheme and interpreters. My job is modifying the following code. If I run

```
(run "sub1(12,2,3,4)")
```

in Drracket, it returns 11. I need to modify the interpreter so that it behaves correctly for a single numeric argument, but returns 0 otherwise (that is, whenever the number of arguments is different from 1, or the argument is of incompatible type)
I understand different modules of the code, but I'm totally confused how to modify it. It would be great if you can help me or give me a pointer to some similar things.

```
#lang eopl

;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;; top level and tests ;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;

(define run
  (lambda (string)
    (eval-program (scan&parse string))))


;; needed for testing
(define equal-external-reps? equal?)

;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;; grammatical specification ;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;

(define the-lexical-spec
  '((whitespace (whitespace) skip)
    (comment ("%" (arbno (not #\newline))) skip)
    (identifier
      (letter (arbno (or letter digit "_" "-" "?")))
      symbol)
    (number (digit (arbno digit)) number)))

(define the-grammar
  '((program (expression) a-program)
    (expression (number) lit-exp)
    (expression (identifier) var-exp)   
    (expression
      (primitive "(" (separated-list expression ",") ")")
      primapp-exp)
    (expression
     ("if" expression "then" expression "else" expression)
      if-exp)
    (expression
      ("let" (arbno  identifier "=" expression) "in" expression)
      let-exp)
    (expression
      ("proc" "(" (separated-list identifier ",") ")" expression)
      proc-exp)
    (expression
      ("(" expression (arbno expression) ")")
      app-exp)
    (expression
       ("begin" expression (arbno ";" expression) "end")
       begin-exp)

    (primitive ("+")     add-prim)
    (primitive ("-")     subtract-prim)
    (primitive ("*")     mult-prim)
    (primitive ("add1")  incr-prim)
    (primitive ("sub1")  decr-prim)
    (primitive ("zero?") zero-test-prim)

    ))

(sllgen:make-define-datatypes the-lexical-spec the-grammar)

(define show-the-datatypes
  (lambda () (sllgen:list-define-datatypes the-lexical-spec the-grammar)))

(define scan&parse
  (sllgen:make-string-parser the-lexical-spec the-grammar))

 (define just-scan
   (sllgen:make-string-scanner the-lexical-spec the-grammar))


 ;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;; the interpreter ;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;

(define eval-program 
   (lambda (pgm)
     (cases program pgm
       (a-program (body)
         (eval-expression body (init-env))))))

 (define eval-expression 
   (lambda (exp env)
    (cases expression exp
      (lit-exp (datum) datum)
      (var-exp (id) (apply-env env id))
      (primapp-exp (prim rands)
         (let ((args (eval-rands rands env)))
          (apply-primitive prim args)))
       (if-exp (test-exp true-exp false-exp) ;\new4
         (if (true-value? (eval-expression test-exp env))
          (eval-expression true-exp env)
          (eval-expression false-exp env)))
      (begin-exp (exp1 exps)
        (let loop ((acc (eval-expression exp1 env))
                   (exps exps))
           (if (null? exps) acc
            (loop (eval-expression (car exps) env) (cdr exps)))))
      (let-exp (ids rands body)  ;\new3
        (let ((args (eval-rands rands env)))
          (eval-expression body (extend-env ids args env))))
       (proc-exp (ids body) (closure ids body env)) ;\new1
       (app-exp (rator rands) ;\new7
         (let ((proc (eval-expression rator env))
              (args (eval-rands rands env)))
          (if (procval? proc)
             (apply-procval proc args)
             (eopl:error 'eval-expression
               "Attempt to apply non-procedure ~s" proc))))
 ;&      
      (else (eopl:error 'eval-expression "Not here:~s" exp))
      )))

;;;; Right now a prefix must appear earlier in the file.

 (define eval-rands
  (lambda (rands env)
    (map (lambda (x) (eval-rand x env)) rands)))

(define eval-rand
  (lambda (rand env)
    (eval-expression rand env)))

(define apply-primitive
   (lambda (prim args)
     (cases primitive prim
       (add-prim  () (+ (car args) (cadr args)))
       (subtract-prim () (- (car args) (cadr args)))
       (mult-prim  () (* (car args) (cadr args)))
       (incr-prim  () (+ (car args) 1))
       (decr-prim  () (- (car args) 1))
;&      
       (zero-test-prim () (if (zero? (car args)) 1 0))
       )))

(define init-env 
   (lambda ()
    (extend-env
      '(i v x)
      '(1 5 10)
      (empty-env))))

;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;; booleans ;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;

(define true-value?
  (lambda (x)
    (not (zero? x))))

;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;; procedures ;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;

(define-datatype procval procval?
  (closure 
    (ids (list-of symbol?)) 
    (body expression?)
    (env environment?)))

(define apply-procval
  (lambda (proc args)
    (cases procval proc
      (closure (ids body env)
        (eval-expression body (extend-env ids args env))))))

;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;; environments ;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;

(define-datatype environment environment?
  (empty-env-record)
  (extended-env-record
    (syms (list-of symbol?))
    (vec vector?)              ; can use this for anything.
    (env environment?))
  )

(define empty-env
  (lambda ()
    (empty-env-record)))

(define extend-env
  (lambda (syms vals env)
    (extended-env-record syms (list->vector vals) env)))

(define apply-env
  (lambda (env sym)
    (cases environment env
      (empty-env-record ()
        (eopl:error 'apply-env "No binding for ~s" sym))
      (extended-env-record (syms vals env)
        (let ((position (rib-find-position sym syms)))
          (if (number? position)
              (vector-ref vals position)
              (apply-env env sym)))))))

(define rib-find-position 
  (lambda (sym los)
    (list-find-position sym los)))

(define list-find-position
  (lambda (sym los)
    (list-index (lambda (sym1) (eqv? sym1 sym)) los)))

(define list-index
   (lambda (pred ls)
    (cond
      ((null? ls) #f)
      ((pred (car ls)) 0)
      (else (let ((list-index-r (list-index pred (cdr ls))))
               (if (number? list-index-r)
                (+ list-index-r 1)
                #f))))))

(define iota
  (lambda (end)
    (let loop ((next 0))
      (if (>= next end) '()
        (cons next (loop (+ 1 next)))))))

(define difference
  (lambda (set1 set2)
    (cond
      ((null? set1) '())
      ((memv (car set1) set2)
       (difference (cdr set1) set2))
       (else (cons (car set1) (difference (cdr set1) set2))))))
```

Comment: The current code return 11 for (run "sub1(12,2,3,4)"). I need to change the code to return 0, because sub1 has more than one argument in this example. It should return 11 in case of (run "sub1(12)") and return 0 in case of (run "sub1(12,2)").

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could change as follows:

```
(define apply-primitive
  [... part of code ...]
      (decr-prim  () (if (and (= (length args) 1) (number? (car args)))
                         (- (car args) 1)
                         0))
  [... rest of code ...]
```

I assume the other primitives should be changed accordingly, this will only change `sub1`.